# ruby decode string (postfilter x-esc-entities)

Tags: ruby, decode

How to decode string `\xC3\xE0\xEB\xE8\xED\xE0.JPG` by ruby?

example of successful decoding (https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en)
[image: Successful decoding]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to convert a Windows-1251 encoded string to UTF-8 or what that site's x-esc-entities filter does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `force_encoding` on the input string, then convert to UTF-8.

```
str = "\xC3\xE0\xEB\xE8\xED\xE0.JPG"
str.force_encoding("cp1251").encode("utf-8", undef: :replace)
=> "Галина.JPG"
```